# Promise.all array of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have this code:

```
 db.group.findOne({_id: id}).then((groupFound) => {
     var membersArray = groupFound.members;

     Promise.all(membersArray.map((member) => {
         return db 
            .doneTodo
            .find({'victor._id': member._id})
            .then((userVictories) => {
                return {
                    email: member.email,
                    victories: userVictories.length
                }
            });
    })).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

The db calls are all MongoDB/Mongoose.

The inside of the array returned from the **map** function is all promises.

The last call:

```
.then((userVictories) => {
    return {
        email: member.email,
        victories: userVictories.length
    }
})
```

returns a promise.

So essentially, after this call is made, what I have is:

```
[promise1, promise2, promise3, ... , promise x]
```

**How are** these promises concluded to change the array value to the value of `promise1.then( (result))`?

Comment: Not certain what Question is? The promise values within `result` should be in the same order as the iterable passed to `Promise.all()`, `membersArray`. What issue are you having?

Comment: @guest271314, I am wondering of the background process. How does Promise.all process all the promises and map the actual "return" value to the array

Comment: What do you mean by "How does Promise.all process all the promises and map the actual "return" value to the array"? If the element of the iterable passed to `Promise.all()` is a `Promise`, the value of the fulfilled or settled `Promise` is passed, else the element is converted to a `Promise`. Note, the `Promise` or value converted to a `Promise` is not necessarily resolved or rejected in sequential order, though the returned array `result` will be in the order of the index of the iterable passed.

Comment: If you are using native Promises (as opposed to a third-party library) then it is handled internally by the V8 engine (promises are part of the language now).

Comment: @guest271314, in the code, EACH of the members of the array is passed a Promise correct? How does map convert those promises?

Comment: `.map()` does not convert a value to a `Promise`. The values of the elements of the iterable passed to `Promise.all()` is converted to a `Promise`, if not already a `Promise` object, by `Promise.all()`. For example `Promise.all([1,2,3]).then(result => console.log(result))`, `Promise.all([1,2,3].map(n => n)).then(result => console.log(result))` return essentially same result. `Promise.all()` converts iterable values to `Promise` object, not `Array.protottpe.map()`.

Comment: @guest271314, but the function gets passed in pending promises? `return {
                                email: member.email,
                                victories: userVictories.length
                            }` returns a promise? So we have an array of unresolved promises?

Comment: EACH of the members of the array is passed a Promise?  No, your arrow function is called once for each member, passed the member and returns a promise.  Map creates a new array of the results (in your case promises but they could be anything).

Comment: @user7361276 Do you mean that `results` is an array of promises? Is  there a missing `})` at first example at Question?

Comment: @djones, yes the array of results is PROMISES right? So how does map convert them into actual values/

Comment: @user7361276 `.map()` does not convert a value of an iterable to `Promise` object. You `return {
                                email: member.email,
                                victories: userVictories.length
                            }` from `.then()`, which also returns a new `Promise` object with value set to the returned plain object. The resulting array elements are the `Promise` values from the `Promise.all()` call. Is there a `.then()` chained to `db.group.findOne()` call? Is `result` an array of plain objects or `Promise` objects? What does `console.log(result)` log?

Answer (score 0):

> How are these promises concluded to change the array value to the value of promise1.then( (result))?

There's nothing special here. The promises within the array will act like any promise does - they will resolve to some value after a period of time, result in an error after some period of time, or if they were set up poorly, never resolve or produce an error.

The purpose of `Promise.all` is simply to wait for all of the values in the array to resolve or for one to throw an error. If they all resolve, the promise returned from `Promise.all` will resolve to an array of all the results. If one throws an error, it will produce that error.

`Promise.all` isn't *doing anything* to the promises, just watching them. We could create our own simple version of `Promise.all` like this:

```js
function myAll(arr) {
    var resolvedCount = 0;
    var resultArray = [];

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (arr.length === 0) {
            resolve([]);
        }
        
        arr.forEach(function (el, i) {
            // wrap el in a promise in case it's not already one
            Promise.resolve(el)
                .then(
                    function (result) {
                        // add result to the result array and increment the count
                        resultArray[i] = result;
                        resolvedCount += 1;
                       
                        if (resolvedCount === arr.length) {
                            // all promises have resolved, 
                            // so this promise can resolve itself
                            resolve(resultArray);
                        }
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        // a promise threw an error. reject
                        reject(err);
                    }
               );  // end of .then()
        });  // end of .forEach()
    });  // end of new Promise()
}



// test out myAll()
function log(value) { console.log(value); }
function logError(value) { log('Error caught:' + value); }


myAll([])
    .then(log, logError);
    
myAll([1, Promise.resolve('apple'), 5, Promise.resolve(7)])
    .then(log, logError);

myAll([2, 3, Promise.reject('no!')])
    .then(log, logError);
```